# Making (Author, Year) citation using Lyx

Tags: lyx, citing

I am doing citations for my master thesis which I just started writing in LyX. How do I cite my references like this: (author, year)? I have googled for like two hours now and nothing seems to work.

I tried to add `\setcitestyle{aysep={<separator>}}` in the preamble
or `round` to `documentclass` and changing `bibliography` to `natbib` with option `authoryear`.

I have also tried adding `natbib` in the preamble, still no dice.

Any ideas are much appreciated. I am very new to LyX so I might need a little elaboration.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? Hint: Not all bibliography styles are capable of producing authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: Currently it is Natlib Author-year, it gives me the following types of citation: Author (Year)

Comment: Let me be more specific: Do you have a `\bibliographystyle` instruction somewhere in your document? If so, what's the argument of `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: No, I do not. I have only changed things in the setting GUI menu.

Comment: If there's no `\bibliographystyle` instruction, BibTeX won't know how it should format the bibliographic entries...

Comment: But what about the settings I have changed? Anywho I got it to work thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- use a bibliography style that can generate authoryear-style citation call-outs,
- load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear`, and
- use the instruction `\citep` to generate "parenthetic" citation call-outs, e.g., `(Author, Year)`, and use `\citet` to generate "textual" citation call-outs, e.g., `Author (Year)`.

Note that some bibliography styles *cannot* generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. E.g., `plain`, `abbrv` and `unsrt` can generate only numeric-style citation call-outs. (Use `plainnat`, `abbrvnat`, and `unsrtnat` instead...)

Comment: I am sorry for what is most likely a dumb question, but how would I load the natbib package with that option? I have that on in the settings under Bibliography

Comment: @nonein - `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.

Comment: Add this under the preamble I assume?

Comment: @nonein - Indeed, all `\usepackage` instructions must occur in the preamble.

Comment: I think I might be in love! It works, I do however have to add \citep in a latex code box. But I suppose that will do! Thank you very much1

Answer (score 2):

Rather than messing around with the preamble, if simple Author-year citations is all you need they can be configured in the document settings.

[image: Lyx settings to enable author-year citations]

If you need more customization than that you should probably start looking at [biblatex](https://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Background#biblatex). That however is not straightforwardly integrated into Lyx and if you intend to customize you'll need to know at least some basic (La)Tex.

Answer (score 0):

A. Generate a BibTeX bibliography using a program like JabRef. Enclose in curly brackets any letter that should be capitalized in any style: The ideas of {A}dam {S}mith. Save the `.bib` file, for example, in the folder of the LyX document.

B. Go to the end of the document and in an empty Standard paragraph Insert > List > BibTeX Bibliography> Add > Browse and choose the `.bib` file generated before. Press Open and Add. Under Style choose any of the following: agsm, apalike, authordate1, ..., authordate4, chicago.

C. Go to Document > Settings...

1. In Modules, make sure that no module like `natlibapa` has been added
2. Go to Bibliography. Under Citation Style choose `Style format: Natlib (BibTeX)`, `Variant: Author-year`. Under Bibliography Style, choose as `Default BibTeX Style:` the one the following that you chose in B: agsm, apalike, authordate1, ..., authordate4, chicago. Under Bibliography Generation, choose `Processor: bibtex8`.

That's it.

If you want more details like `doi` in your list of references, then change the previous as follows:

B. Go to the end of the document and click the `BibTeX Generated Bibliography`. Choose `Style: apacite`.

C. 1. Go to Modules and add `natlibapa`.

C. 2. Go to Bibliography. Under Bibliography Style, choose `Default BibTeX Style: apacite`.